# Xcode won't run app on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Yesterday I uninstalled my App Store install of XCode and installed it manually from the Apple developer site.

I had 9.4.1 and downloaded 9.3

Ever since I've not been able to run any apps on the simulator.

I see the following error in xcode:

[image: Xcode error message]

I see this error in the Xcode logs:

```
iOSSimulator: 56E6A4AD-4D6F-4CB4-A666-E1DE0D49B101: Failed to launch app with identifier: com.mikevelu.Test and options: {

"activate_suspended" = 0;

arguments =     (

);

environment =     {

    "DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH" = "/Users/mikemurray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqvnwaelkrhrooepamzxmakiidkf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator";

    "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" = "/Applications/Xcode9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Applications/Xcode9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Develope<…>
```

and I see this error in the simulator logs:

```
(UIKitApplication:com.mikevelu.Test[0xf61e][2808][2983]): Service could not initialize: 99Z999: xpcproxy_sim + 9282 [1524][AF02A7E2-099C-3F21-AB91-5AA7DB3FFA58]: 0x5
```

I've tried the usual culprits, removing derived data/cleaning build folder/restarting simulator/restarting xcode/restarting macbook.

I've also tried completely uninstalling xcode and reinstalling (uninstalled 9.3 and tried installing 9.4.1), doesn't seem to make any difference.

Seen a few similar questions posted and one of the most common fixes seems to be removing any checked blank environment variables in the scheme, I can't find any to remove. I've tried running both in debug and release, I've tried disabling Debug executable and selecting the executable on launch. Also tried deleting the scheme and creating a new one.

Also set verbose logging on the simulator and I didn't get any more illuminating information.

If if install the app manually using simctl and launch it using simctl it will launch without complaints (that's what prompted me to try disabling debug executable).

I see this issue regardless of which project/workspace I have open in Xcode, the example I'm using currently is just a blank project I created to try and get to the bottom of the issue.

I'm edging closer and closer to a complete restore being the most logical next step, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Things to try when Xcode acts up: remove derived data, clean the project, restart Xcode.

Comment: Tried those @kevin see: "I've tried the usual culprits, removing derived data/cleaning build folder/restarting simulator/restarting xcode/restarting macbook." in my question. 

Posted an answer since which seems to have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT - Discovered the issue was with anti virus not liking it when xcode wasn't named Xcode.app. Sigh.

So, it looks like renaming the Xcode.app file now leads to some pretty ropey behaviour.

Up till now when managing multiple installs of xcode I'd just rename the files to something like Xcode.9.4.1.app, not sure when/if that's changed but the only way I can fix the simulator issue is to keep the Xcode.app filename.

Comment: Does your AV software limit the directories from which programs can execute? Xcode contains a number of applications within its bundle, and the simulator is one of them, so it may just be a matter of telling your AV software to allow execution from `Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Applications` or whatever.

Comment: Yep it's a wee bit more tricky than that as the Xcode-x.x.x part is variable (it's just the version number of the particular version of Xcode). Apparently it's not possible to use regex or any variables in the whitelist so any time I need to have more than one version of xcode installed I'd need to update for the new Xcode.app filename. Which isn't ideal and doesn't scale, need a different approach I think.

Comment: Sounds like different anti-virus software is called for. Alternatively, write a script that updates the whitelist.